# addeventlistener click only working on first click

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Been trying to recreate the old palm pilot dope wars game and can't figure out what part of the code is messing this up.  Trying to add 1 to the value when you click the + button.  Here is the code thanks!

```
init: function(){
  this.acid = document.getElementById('acid');
  this.acidQty = document.getElementById('acidQty');
  this.acidAdd = document.getElementById('acidAdd');
},
// bind the events to the button
bindEvents: function(){
  this.acidAdd.addEventListener('click', this.addAcid.bind(this), false);
  // $("#acidAdd").on('click', this.addAcid.bind(this));
},
//Get the value
getQty: function(){
  this.acidQuantity = $('#acidQty').val();
},
//get current value and add 1
addAcid: function(){
  this.getQty();
  this.acidQuantity ++;
  this.updateQuantity();
},
// update the value on the html
updateQuantity: function(){
  this.acidQty.innerText = this.acidQuantity;
},
```

Here is a jsbin of all the code incase I missed something else

http://jsbin.com/wakoqeduwo/1/edit?html

Comment: The code is not complete enough: please provide the code where you define your variables, like `this.aidAdd`. Also the code where you call `bindEvents`.

Comment: The `updateQuantity` method appears to be missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to tell without seeing all the code, but I believe the following changes should work.

```
this.acidQuantity: 1,

bindEvents: function(){
   this.acidAdd.addEventListener.addEventListener('click', this.addAcid);
},

addAcid: function(){
  this.updateQuantity();
  this.acidQuantity ++;
},

updateQuantity: function() {
    $('#acidQty').html(app.acidQuantity); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks that does work.  Can you not grab the value from the html and add values from that??

Comment: you can. change your `getQty()` method to the following `getQty: function(){this.acidQuantity = parseInt($('#acidQty').html());}`

Comment: omg. It's cuz i was pulling in a string not an int wasn't it.   ehhhhh.  Thank you soooo much Paul!!!

Comment: Yep, it is a string that is pulled in, so you need to change that to a number. Also, `.val` is generally used to take the input from forms. You should use `.html` to get the value of the element